# Mocha force fail after an infinite retries

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

Take this code for example:

```
const assert = require("assert");
describe('Force fail after iterations', function () {
    var retriesDone = 0;
    it('Math.random will be eventually give the same numbers', function () {
        this.retries(Infinite);
        retriesDone++;
        var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        assert.equal(a,b);
    });
});
```

This will get executed for (n) number of times then gives this result in my console:

```
       Force fail after iterations
        √ Math.random will be eventually give the same numbers
```

However I have no idea how many retries Mocha went through to have equal numbers of `Math.random`.

In a real world project that I'm working on, if the retries were less than 50 then my function is weak, if it's more than 50 then it's good. So I need to know exactly how many iterations were done.

I can do this of course:

```
if(a===b) console.log("Retries:",retriesDone);
```

but it will output the result out of indentation, like this:

```
      Force fail after iterations
Retries: 1
        √ Math.random will be eventually give the same numbers
```

I don't feel that this is the best approach to do force-fail testing in Mocha! is there a better way?

*Note: What I mean by force-fail testing,  is like when testing an airplane wings resistance by applying a weight of (n)Kg then (n)+100Kg, (n)+200Kg,(n)+500Kg,(n)+900Kg ..etc.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mocha's retrying capability was not designed to do what you are doing. I'd do something like this instead of writing convoluted code that attempts to bend `retries()` to do something it was not designed for.

```
describe('Force fail after iterations', function () {
    it('Math.random will be eventually give the same numbers', function () {
        var tried = 0;
        // When we have done 50 tries, we deem the function to be 
        // "strong" and consider it a success.
        while (tried < 50) {
            tried++;
            var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            if (a === b) {
                throw new Error("function is weak");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.. for anyone coming to this thread, check this code and the comments

```
describe('Force fail after iterations', function () {
    var retriesDone = 0;
    it('Math.random will be eventually give the same numbers', function () {
        this.retries(Infinite);
        retriesDone++;
        var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        if(a === b) { // when we get an equal values
            // if the retries were more than 50, we're good
            if(retriesDone>50) assert.equal(h1,h2); 
            else {
                // if it were more than 50, then we'll give assertion error
                // but we need to set the retries to 50
                // so no more retires after this failure will occur
                this.retries(0);
                assert.ifError(Error("Retries were less than 50"));
            }
        }
        assert.equal(a,b);
    });
});
```